# messageCollector filter [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to create a MessageCollector with several users,
So, i can do like that :

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(channel, m =>
     m.author.id === "123456789" ||
     m.author.id === "978654321"
, { max: 2000, maxMatches: 2000 });
```

But, i have an Array ID :

```
let array = ["123456789","987654321",...]
```

How replace the "123456789" in collector by array[0] ?

Or how do this that with another method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to collect messages in a the channel for authors who have an Id that matches one that is in your array of Ids.

The second argument provided the [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector) is a filter function.  The filter function in your example is filtering based on whether an author has the id 123456789 or 978654321.

To do the same with the array, one option would be:

```
let array = ["123456789","987654321",...];
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(channel, m => array.includes(m.author.id)), { max: 2000, maxMatches: 2000 });
```

If you are handling large volumes of messages, you may want to look into further optimization of this function, but this should get you started.

See here for [info on includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).